# Access to fetch from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/NAMES.pdf net::ERR_FAILED 200

I'm having a problem with the viewing of my PDF.

Whenever I view a photos it does work.

MY FRONTEND:

data return

```
   viewAppointmentFileData: [],
   viewAppointmentFilePDFData: [],


  
<div v-else-if="myAppointment.fileExtension == 'pdf'"
                                  >
                                    <q-btn
                                      class="q-ma-sm"
                                      icon="preview"
                                      color="positive"
                                      @click="openFilePDF(myAppointment)"
                                      label="View"
                                    />
```

The viewing of the PDF.

```
<q-dialog v-model="viewAppointmentFilePDF">
              <q-card style="width: 600px; max-width: 80vw">
                <div class="q-pa-md">
                  <pdf
                    class="q-pa-sm text-center"
                    :src="
                      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/${viewAppointmentFilePDFData.file}`
                    "
                    width="115"
                    height="115"
                  />
                </div>
              </q-card>
            </q-dialog>
```

My method.

```
 myAppointmentData() {
      try {
        const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem("Bearer");

        this.$axios
          .get(
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/all-appointments",

            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
              }
            }
          )
          .then(response => {
            this.myAppointments = response.data;

            console.log("Appointment", this.myAppointments);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

I get this error in the console.

[image]

Error in the Network.

[image]

and the Header gives me a 200 status code and I don't get why it's always been blocking.

[image]

I have allowed everything in the cors.php. I have set the proxy in my quasar framework to 10.30.154.253 (cause I'll be converting this to android cordova in quasar.) and I have allowed it in the backend.

```
'paths' => ['api/*', '/storage/images', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie','login','registration', 'myProfile', 'signout'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ["http://127.0.0.1:8000", "http://10.30.154.253:8080"],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

my Laravel controller for the query.

```
  public function allAppointment()
    {
        $appointment = DB::table('appointments')
        ->select(
            'appointments.id',
            'appointments.name',
            'appointments.branch',
            'appointments.test',
            'appointments.date',
            'appointments.time',
            'appointments.status',
            'appointments.addressofHomeService',
            'appointments.type',
            'appointments.otherconcerns',
            'appointments.remarks',
            'appointments.file',
            'appointments.fileExtension',
            'appointments.created_at'
        )
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'appointments.user_id')
        ->orderBy('appointments.created_at','desc')
        // ->where('items.activeInactive', '=', 'Active')
        ->get();

        return response()->json($appointment);
    }
```

I also tried following the links here. https://www.positronx.io/how-to-enable-cors-in-laravel/?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com and similar to this, still it hasn't been able to work.

How can I fix this?